# Android hand over ByteArray to Host Card Emulation Service

Tags: android, kotlin, hce

how can i hand over from my activity a ByteArray to the Host Card Emulation (HCE) service?

I tryed it with an Intent.putExtra() like this:

```
    val cert: ByteArray
    val intent = Intent(this, MyHostApduService::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("byteArray", cert)
        startService(intent)
```

In the HCE service i can not access the intent anymore!
Like this:

```
 val cert = intent.getByteArrayExtra("byteArray")
```

How can I hand over the byte array?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your code `val cert: ByteArray` is not null (did you initialize it)?

Comment: Try to change `val cert: ByteArray` to `val cert = byteArrayOf(//your values: 1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the the HCE service there is a method which can be overreaden like this:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)


    if (intent!!.hasExtra("<KEY>")) {
        var arr = intent.getByteArrayExtra("<KEY>")
    }


    return flags
}
```